# Form Handling Using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I know this may be trivial but I can't seem to figure out how to send user submitted data on my webpage to the server side. I am making a simple web app that takes in a users' word and then counts the number of syllables on the server side using `Python`.

I render the page using flask:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
  webPage = open('pg.html','r')
  return webPage.read()
```

In `JavaScript` I have a `form`:

```
<form method="get"><br><br> 
  Enter a Word: <br>
 <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
```

When the user submits a word to this form, how do I retrieve it with  `Python` ?

I've read around about  `GET`  and  `POST`  methods but I am still pretty confused.

Comment: A form is a `POST` request to an action. Have a look at [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you know about `GET` and `POST`, here is the important bits.

Show the home(hello) page

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')
```

Now, in the `hello.html` (notice the action and method):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/testpost">
            Enter a Word: <br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you notice, the method is `POST` that means, your data is a sent as a `POST` to the server. Now to handle the `POST` request, we can consider the following:

**Now POST handling**

```
@app.route('/testpost', methods = ['POST'])
def postTesting():
    name = request.form['name']
    print name #This is the posted value
```

You see, the `request.form` contains the parsed form data.

Comment: Now, one question, what exactly is  action = "/testpost"  doing? Is it that creating a new page?

Comment: @DeseanAbraham It's a URL to your `POST`. (The URI of a program) So, when you say: `action="/testpost"`, it means a url as "http://localhost/testpost" with `POST` data. (considering localhost is your hosted server)

Comment: It's kind of necessary if you want to send the data. (not the only way). "testpost" is just an example. You can provide any URI name you wish. it will post your data to that URI. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Comment: Okay, I'm having one problem. When I submit to the form and it attempts to redirect to this new URL I get a URL NOT FOUND error.

Comment: The `URL not found` simply means the `app.route` is not having the same. It should have been added somewhere.

Comment: The `app.route` has the same URL as does the form in `JavaScript`. I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Is it perhaps beacuse I am using `urlib` and you are using `render_template` to display the page?

Comment: Just try to check how the app.route is usually defined. Check for `app = Flask(__name__)` after you import Flask. I'm not able to give you proper help now because I'm using my phone.